# Ruby Program isn't returning results from httparty get request

Tags: ruby, uri, httparty

I am having issues with the following code. I am not getting any errors but for some reason my results are coming back empty every time I use a search keyword that has a space in the string. I have tried using urleescape but that also doesn't work. Does anyone have any insight?

```
require 'httparty'
require 'uri'

class Recipe
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'recipepuppy.com'
  default_params onlyImages: "1"
  format :json

  #Uses request parameter to send to API
  def self.for(q)
    q = URI.escape(q)
    p q
    get("/api", query: {q: q})["results"]
  end

end

puts Recipe.for "chocolate"
puts Recipe.for "apple pie"
```

Comment: Haven't used httparty in a long time, but when I change your code to `results = get("/api", query: {q: q}); p results.request.last_uri.to_s` it shows as `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api?onlyImages=1&q=apple%252520pie`, so it's escaping your escaped space, if I remove your `URI.escape`, it still shows as `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api?onlyImages=1&q=apple%2520pie`, though...it looks like it's double escaping it's own escaping, spent 10 minutes or so looking into that, but w/o much luck...maybe it'll set someone else down a better path

Comment: Solved the issue. I needed to add this to the base_uri:                  
`base_uri 'http://www.recipepuppy.com'`